# Cannot boot from newly bought SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, laptop, ssd

I have a Toshiba Satellite P745 Laptop.

I bought a new Kingston UV400 SSDNow SSD 120GB. I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 as my OS (in laptop). I've downloaded Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit yesterday, because I want to change my OS to Windows 7.

After putting the SSD inside an enclosure, I did the following steps:

1. Right-clicked the .iso file of Windows 7.
2. Pointed to Open With -> Disk Image Writer.
3. Wrote the image to SSD.

After that I put my SSD inside my laptop to install Windows 7, but it shows me this error:

[image]

The boot sequence is as follows:

1. HDD / SSD
2. USB
3. ODD
4. LAN

Update:  My HDD properly boots Ubuntu in my laptop, but I cannot do it in SSD.

Comment: That's not how it works. You cannot directly boot from an ISO file. You need to burn the ISO image to a DVD and boot into it to install Windows.

Comment: This question is basically: "How do I install Windows 7?" with a misleading title.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think writing an OS installer to a SSD directly is quite right, and disk image writer may not be right tool for the job - it essentially DDs the contents of the ISO to a drive when usually some extra work needs to be done to convert a livecd to a liveiso. This [Askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu) suggests a few options - of which karel's option of [winusb seems the best](https://askubuntu.com/posts/489556/revisions)

Write it to an USB drive - Boot that and install *from that to* the SSD. Alternately use a optical drive burner software like brasero or k3b to burn the image to a suitable optical disk.

There's ways to directly apply a windows install to a drive, but none would work from linux